# split students by success

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

i have 5 region that students wants to go. Every region has quota.
For example

- region A has 3
- region B has 2
- region C has 1
- region D has 2
- region E has 1

And i have 9 students. (total quota and student number is same ) and student list is ordered by their success.
My problem is i will send students to region with order like first student needs to go A if quote is not full second will go to B if quote is not full

For the example above i need a string like;
A,B,C,D,E,A,B,D,A
This means

- 1st, 5th and 9th student will go region A
- 2,7 -> B
- c   -> C
- 4,8 -> D
- 5   -> E

i did already an algorithm for this but it works really slow for 100k student.

```
public String split(int quotoA, int quotoB, int quotoC, int quotoD, int quotoE) {
    boolean AdidNotGetYet = true, BdidNotGetYet = true, CdidNotGetYet = true, DdidNotGetYet = true, EdidNotGetYet = true;

    StringBuffer list = new StringBuffer();
    while (true) {
        if (quotoA > 0 && AdidNotGetYet) {
            list.append(",A");
            AdidNotGetYet = false;
            quotoA--;
        } else if (quotoB > 0 && BdidNotGetYet) {
            list.append(",B");
            BdidNotGetYet = false;
            quotoB--;
        } else if (quotoC > 0 && CdidNotGetYet) {
            list.append(",C");
            CdidNotGetYet = false;
            quotoC--;
        } else if (quotoD > 0 && DdidNotGetYet) {
            list.append(",D");
            DdidNotGetYet = false;
            quotoD--;
        } else if (quotoE > 0 && EdidNotGetYet) {
            list.append(",E");
            EdidNotGetYet = false;
            quotoE--;
        } else {
            AdidNotGetYet = true;
            BdidNotGetYet = true;
            CdidNotGetYet = true;
            DdidNotGetYet = true;
            EdidNotGetYet = true;
        }

        if (quotoA == 0 && quotoB == 0 && quotoC == 0 && quotoD == 0 && quotoE == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    list.deleteCharAt(0);
    return list.toString();
}
```

Comment: `c -> C` ?? --- `5 -> E` when 5th student will go region A ??

Comment: What is the exactly problem ? What do you mean by *slow* ? What do you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html); and simply loop while any of the quotas remain greater than zero. I would also shorten the variable names. And since it uses no class state, I would make it `static`. All of those boolean flags to enforce sequence are pointless (and they are making your loop iterate **many** extra times), so I would eliminate them. Like,

```
public static String split(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
    while (a > 0 || b > 0 || c > 0 || d > 0 || e > 0) {
        if (a > 0) {
            sj.add("A");
            a--;
        }
        if (b > 0) {
            sj.add("B");
            b--;
        }
        if (c > 0) {
            sj.add("C");
            c--;
        }
        if (d > 0) {
            sj.add("D");
            d--;
        }
        if (e > 0) {
            sj.add("E");
            e--;
        }
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Tested with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(split(3, 2, 1, 2, 1));
}
```

Outputs

```
A,B,C,D,E,A,B,D,A
```

If you'd prefer to not use `StringJoiner`, at least prefer [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html). As the `StringBuffer` javadoc notes *The `StringBuilder` class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.*

```
public static String split(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (a > 0 || b > 0 || c > 0 || d > 0 || e > 0) {
        if (a > 0) {
            sb.append(",A");
            a--;
        }
        if (b > 0) {
            sb.append(",B");
            b--;
        }
        if (c > 0) {
            sb.append(",C");
            c--;
        }
        if (d > 0) {
            sb.append(",D");
            d--;
        }
        if (e > 0) {
            sb.append(",E");
            e--;
        }
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

**Added by Andreas**

If you use varargs, the code becomes smaller because it can use a nested loop, and allows a dynamic number of regions (up to 26).

```
static String assignRoundRobin(int... quotas) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
    for (int remain = 1; remain > 0; ) {
        remain = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < quotas.length; i++) {
            if (quotas[i] > 0) {
                sj.add(String.valueOf((char) ('A' + i)));
                remain += --quotas[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return sj.toString();
}
```

Comment: Don't know why you have down-vote. You got my up-vote. Though I'd suggest using varargs, for shorter code, and to allow dynamic number of regions. Adding code example to your answer, hope that's ok with you.

Comment: This is what i need